# Warning: CredentialId "timer" could not be found. Authentication failed for '<git_url>'

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins parameterized pipeline which works properly when build manually. But when I try to schedule this pipeline using 'Build periodically with parameters' option, it gives below error at the time of git checkout:

Schedule:

```
H 4 * * * % AGENT=developer ;CHECKOUT_USING_USER=developer
```

Error:

```
The recommended git tool is: NONE
Warning: CredentialId "timer" could not be found.
Wiping out workspace first.
Cloning the remote Git repository
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress <git_url> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for '<git_url>'
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2732)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2109)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:623)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:850)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:158)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:151)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to nikhshah-jen-agt-prd-5
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1784)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1000)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:143)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor901.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:129)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy287.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1226)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1309)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:129)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:97)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:84)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] echo
Exception occured : hudson.AbortException: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
```

The pipeline starts its execution at specified time but it is giving error at the time of git checkout.

Comment: Seems like you have used some variable as git credential id, which is getting assigned to 'timer', It would be helpful if you provide checkout step's code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use the build user ID as the credential ID. When a pipeline is triggered on schedule, the build user ID is `timer`, so Jenkins looks for the corresponding credentials.

You didn't provide your Jenkinsfile example so the only recommendation possible at this point would be to create the credential with ID "timer" that will be used to checkout the code when the build is triggered automatically.